# faceMocion input tag not get bind in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i use `<input type="hidden" value="asombro" class="facemocion" />` in body then its work correctly ,
but when i try  to bind same tag with jQuery like

```
 html= html + "<input type="hidden" value="asombro" class="facemocion" />"
```

it not get work

Comment: what is the error on console?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use single quotes for the string:

```
html += '<input type="hidden" value="asombro" class="facemocion" />';
```

Or escape the double quotes inside it:

```
html += "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"asombro\" class=\"facemocion\" />";
```

Comment: i use facemocion.js which create <div dato-descripcion="like" id-referencia="1464612869949" class="Selector selectorFace  amo"></div>           and                                                                               <input value="like" class="facemocion 1464612869949" style="display: none;"> but when i use in js it takes  '<input type="hidden" value="asombro" class="facemocion" />' as only hidden tag or string

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like more jquery way rather than creating it as string,

```
var hidden = $("<input>", {
  type: 'hidden',
  value: 'asombro',
  'class': 'facemoion'
});
$("body").append(hidden);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try make this way.

```
 html += '<input type="hidden" value="asombro" class="facemocion"/>

$('body').append(html);
```

now use the plugin.

```
$('.facemocion').faceMocion();
```